Statistical analyses after propensity score matching with matchit - Survival analysis- adjustment?
For an analysis of a data set I applied propensity score matching (matchit in R, 5:1, without replacement), which went very well- I dod not lose too much of the sample and got a balanced data set out of it.
However, I'm wondering whether the matching affects my further analyses? With the matched sample, I performed some tests afterwards and, for example, applied log rank tests and also calculated confidence intervals for Kaplan Meier Curves applying Greenwood's formula. I see that the matching itself produces some additional "error" in the estimations- so I want to adjust for the previous matching procedure using robust standard errors.
I searched for literature but I did not find a clear recommendation. If I understood correctly, I could add weights, cluster and robust=TRUE to survfit objects in order to consider robust standard errors and, e.g., adjusted versions of log-rank tests?
For the log-rank test, this would look like this:
coxph(Surv(time, status)~ treatment, data = matched.data , robust = TRUE, 
                             weights = weights, cluster = subclass)

and I would take the p-values of the robust score test. Is this correct?
Thanks a lot!

Besides losing a lot of power and being quite arbitrary, matching leads to the need for specialized analyses as you thought.  The choice of a unique analysis that respects the matching is arbitrary.  You’re on the right track but might have terrible power.  Also you have jettisoned easily explained outcome heterogeneity by ignoring prognostic factors.  What got you away from covariate adjustment (which solves all these problems)?  See also this.

Thank you very much for your comment. it was not just my decision and we ended up with propensity score matching which is fixed for now. Indeed, the loss of power is visible. However, at the moment, I only care about the 100% correctness of the statistical method I chose and this seems to be okay at least. Of note- p values changed from 0.7 to 0.6 or something, so no impact on the interpretations here.

By the way- I'm not interested in the HR at all, I just want to perform a log-rank test in a correct way. But this is only working with coxph in my case, right?

A method that loses power is not correct.  And the log-rank test is just a special case of the Cox PH model.  Log-rank assumes PH just as much as the Cox model does.

Thanks, Frank. But the PH assumption is a different thing here. My question was about how to incorporate the matched nature of the data into my analyses. The log-rank test itself was not correct anyway, even prior to matching (as we don't have proportional hazards). It was requested by reviewers, but is not meaningful here. However, I just want to ensure that I use the correct adjustments fpr the matched data in my methods.

Good luck finding a unique principled way to do this in the context of a somewhat ad hoc procedure.  And note that the approach you are seeking covers up interactions with exposure and doens’t model all-important outcome heterogeneity.
